# Flutter FutureBuilder with Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, future

I'm trying to create a list in flutter, loading data asynchronously from firestore for each cell:

```
Future getUserDetails(String userID) async {
    DatabaseService databaseService =
        DatabaseService(currentUserId: _currentUserID);
    return databaseService.getUserDetails(userID: userID);
  }

Future sampleText() async {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) => randomString(5));
}

FutureBuilder _userAsyncCell(ClassAttendee attendeeData) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getUserDetails(attendeeData.userId),//sampleText(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          else if (snapshot.hasData)
            return Text("DATA: ${snapshot.data}");
          else if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Text("ERROR: ${snapshot.error}");
          else
            return Text('None');
        });
  }
```

AND in the DatabaseService:

```
final CollectionReference _usersCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<User> getUserDetails({String userID}) async {
    print('Fetching User public data ${userID}');
    _usersCollection.document(userID).get().then((userJSON) {
      User user = User.fromJson(userJSON.data);
      print("Received user info: ${user.identifier}");
      return user;
    });
  }
```

The issue is that the data received in the futureBuilder is always nil.

When using the `sampleText()` instead of `getUserDetails()`, it's working properly.

Do you have any ideas why is this happening?

EDIT:
In logs I can see, that the userDetails is properly returning the value and the futureBuilder's builder is called:[image]

```
flutter: Fetching User public data Rh8snwoI27V6pA3wkmQwBPitgl63
flutter: Received user info: Rh8snwoI27V6pA3wkmQwBPitgl63
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Refactoring your code as follows.

You are not awaiting the response and hence the future returns with `nil` value

```
Future<User> getUserDetails({String userID}) async {
    print('Fetching User public data ${userID}');
    await _usersCollection.document(userID).get().then((userJSON) {
      User user = User.fromJson(userJSON.data);
      print("Received user info: ${user.identifier}");
      return user;
    });
}
```

Comment: I however DO NOT recommend using .then() and async await together, await and assign the .get() result to a variable which will hold the response from firebase (Precisely it will have the value of userJSON in this context)

Comment: Thanks. You're right, hence I've switched to using stream and observing the userDetails in it using firestore snapshots.